# Function to return a difference between two complex nested json with json array<Unordered>

Tags: java, json

The objective here is to compare two json files and print the difference between two of the files.
Its a nested JSON file with nested JSON array. The idea is to keep the reference file constant and compare the newly created file with reference.

Issue here is since the order of JSON parameter is varying every time and the below code is comparing line for line the validation Its flattening the JSON and making that as key value pair and comparing.Its failing because the order is not maintained. please note that the JSON file has 300k lines and ordering using a particular field doesn't work.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();

Map<String, Object> expMap = gson.fromJson(expectedJson, type);//expectedJson- json file parsed as a string
Map<String, Object> actMap = gson.fromJson(foundJson, type);
List<String> expMsgList=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> actMsgList=new ArrayList<>();
logger.info("Flatten the map inorder to compare the Nested JSON objects");
Map<String, Object> expFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(expMap);
Map<String, Object> actFlatMap = FlatMapUtil.flatten(actMap);
MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(expFlatMap, actFlatMap);


if(expMap.keySet().equals(actMap.keySet())) {
    if(!difference.entriesDiffering().isEmpty()) {
        difference.entriesDiffering().forEach((key, value) ->{
            String keyString=null;
            String keyStringarr[]=key.split("/");;
            
                keyString=keyStringarr[keyStringarr.length -1];
            
            
            if(!(fieldSkip.contains(keyString))){ //tp skip few parameters
                String valueExp=value.toString().split(",")[0].split("\\(")[1];
                String valueAct=value.toString().split(",")[1].split("\\)")[0];
                    
                
                String valueforKey="EXPECTED_VALUE="+valueExp+" and ACTUAL_VALUE="+ valueAct;
                failedItems.put(key, valueforKey); 
                logger.info(key + " -->"+valueforKey );
                }
            }
            );
```

Utility file for flattening the json file

```
package com.cisco.cnp.commonUtils;

import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class FlatMapUtil {

    private FlatMapUtil() {
        throw new AssertionError("No instances");
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(FlatMapUtil::flatten)
                .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put("/" + e.getKey(), e.getValue()), LinkedHashMap::putAll);
    }

    private static Stream<Entry<String, Object>> flatten(Entry<String, Object> entry) {

        if (entry == null) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }

        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            Map<?, ?> properties = (Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue();
            return properties.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> flatten(new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey() + "/" + e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
        }

        if (entry.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) entry.getValue();
            return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<String, Object>(entry.getKey() + "/" + i, list.get(i)))
                    .flatMap(FlatMapUtil::flatten);
        }

        return Stream.of(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "Approaches tried method" mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter   code snippet for the approach I did by flattening the json and comparing using hashmap. 
"Approaches tried method" - this was a typo. I stated the method i tried

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.

Comment: Sure @JamesZ . thanks for correcting. PS I was not able to find a common json parameter to sort the JSON array accordingly